# Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, login, firebase-auth

.
Hola comunidad tengo una duda! Estoy haciendo el login de mi proyecto de Angular 13 y Firebase, la primera ves que lo implemente funciono a la primer (demasiado facil), lamentablemente por un error en el archivo original me tuve que mover al respaldo del proyecto. Ahora implemento el login pero no accede, nose si me estaria faltando algo o solo tengo un error por otra cosa. alguno me puede ayudar un poco?

**Este es mi servicio**

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth:Auth) { }

  login({ email, password } :any){
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);
  }

  logout(){
    return signOut(this.auth);
  }

}
```

**Este es mi componente ts**

```html
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formLogin: FormGroup;

  constructor(private auth:AuthService, private router:Router){

    this.formLogin = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(),
      password: new FormControl()
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.auth.login(this.formLogin.value)
    .then( result =>{
      this.router.navigate(['/Crud'])
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }


}
```

**Este es mi html**

```html
<section class="container-fluid" style="margin: 20rem;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input  type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Password</label>
                  <input  type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button (click)="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
              </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

En consola retrona
*POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyAmkC-oPrt4fI1DwhWgg1EgJ6mekY5tFnc 400. FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/missing-email).*

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante descriptivo.

antes de llamar a la function de login de firebase, has un log de los parametros que le envias, seguramente, por alguna razon. el email no estara definido